# In Need of the Most Simple Haskell Program

Tags: haskell

Can anyone provide me with less than five lines of code that I can save as .hs and run as a haskell program and see the magic happen? The internet is so complicated sometimes.

Comment: `echo "main = return ()" | runhaskell`, since you asked for the "most simple" program. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

From http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_5_steps

The internet isn't so bad!

Comment: Lol i tied to write exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 11):

Someone should have mentioned `interact` which is simple and actually practical:

```
main = interact reverse
```

```
$ cat interact.hs | runhaskell interact.hs
esrever tcaretni = niam
```

and thus with

```
main = interact (unwords . reverse . words)
```

```
$ cat interact.hs | runhaskell interact.hs
words) . reverse . (unwords interact = main
```

or with an import

```
import Data.List
 main = interact (intersperse '\n')
```

```
$ echo "hello" | runhaskell interact.hs
h
e
l
l
o
```

or, now compiling:

```
main = interact showCharcount 
  where showCharcount str = show (length str) ++ "\n"
```

```
$ ghc --make -O2 interact.hs -o charcount
$ echo "hello world" | ./charcount
12
```

In which case it makes sense to start doing a bit of poor man's benchmarking:

```
$ time cat /usr/share/dict/words | ./charcount
2486813
real 0m0.096s
```

Answer (score 7):

This answer's more focused on "seeing the magic happen":

```
data Expression = Greeting | Leaving

f :: Expression -> String
f Greeting = "Hi there!"
f Leaving  = "Ok, bye!"

main = putStrLn (f Greeting)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about all the Fibonacci numbers?  Well, you can just print something like 100 of them for brevity.. ;)

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
main = print $ take 100 fibs
```

Answer (score 4):

Hamming numbers are numbers that don't have any prime factors larger than 5.  I.e. they have the form 2^i*3^j*5^k.  The first 20 of them are:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,27,30,32,36]
```

The 500000th one is:

```
1962938367679548095642112423564462631020433036610484123229980468750
```

The program that printed the 500000th one (after a brief moment of computation) is:

```
merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys) =
  case (x`compare`y) of
    LT -> x:merge xs yys
    EQ -> x:merge xs ys
    GT -> y:merge xxs ys

hamming = 1 : m 2 `merge` m 3 `merge` m 5
  where
    m k = map (k *) hamming

main = print (hamming !! 499999)
```

That's longer than the 5 lines of code you wanted.  Of course it could be golfed, but I'd rather write it naturally and see how many lines it takes you to compute that number in any other language, with reasonable execution time.

Answer (score 3):

[Good quick start into Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: I look forward to diving into this tutorial. Thanks demas.

Answer (score 3):

Print every number:

```
main = mapM_ print [1..]
```

Comment: `print` automatically appends new lines since it is equivalent to `putStrLn . show`, so it will display output under all buffering schemes.  I also just tested each buffering scheme, to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

You could go cheery. Here `greet` is a function that takes a name and makes a greeting out of it:

```
greet xs = "\nHello, " ++ xs

main = do
   putStrLn $ unlines ["Hi! I'm a Haskell program.", "Who are you?"]
   fmap greet getLine >>= putStrLn
```

`main` uses `unlines` to turn a list of strings into a single newline-separated string, then prints it with `putStrLn`.
`getLine` returns a user-entered line of text (without the newline character) then applies `greet` to that. Finally we push that as input into another `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 2):

This one's a bit dense, and definitely not the simplest, but it does use the infinite list `[1..]` which you could call magic.

```
described name list = putStrLn ("\n" ++ name) >> mapM_ print (zip [1..] list)
main = let somenums = [1..100] in do
   described "Some cubes:" [ x^3 | x <- somenums]
   described "Some powers:" $ map (2^) somenums
   described "Some triangle numbers:" $ scanl (+) 0 somenums
```

The `described` function prints a description and then prints a list paired (zipped) with their position.
I use it on a few number sequences. Whole number data defaults to `Integer`, which is why it can happily tell you `2^100`. The `Int` data type is more limited, (`maxBound :: Int == 2147483647`), but of course takes less time and space.

Comment: Wow that's powerful. Might be a little too much for my brain to handle just yet lol. But I shall return to this comment in the near future. Thanks AndrewC!

Answer (score 1):

From [Tutorials/Programming Haskell/String IO](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/String_IO) note multiple start-up short and simple examples; for instance the equivalent to bash `cat < myFile.txt`,

```
main = interact id
```

where `interact` applies a function (in this case the identity function `id`) onto the contents from the standard input (here `myFile.txt`).

Compile and run it as follows,

```
ghc --make short.hs
./short < myFile.txt
```